# Are there galaxy clusters or dark matter halos in the void?

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, galaxy-cluster

The void usually refers to the region of the Universe where the overdensity $\delta(x)$ is less than zero. What I'm curious about is whether there are virialized objects, like galaxy clusters or dark matter halos, living in such an underdense environment.

Comment: There are certainly *galaxies* in voids, so there are virialized dark-matter halos. Probably no actual clusters, though.

Comment: @PeterErwin Why galaxies can live in voids theoretically?

Comment: In practice any kind. Spirals seem more common in these quiescent environments.

Comment: @WangYun A void is where the *average* overdensity is low. There will still be local variations, though, so there can be regions within a void where the local overdensity is large enough for gravitational collapse of a halo to take place. (Such regions will be much less common in a void, of course.)

Comment: @PeterErwin Thank you for your reply.